Incrementing the value of a cell based off of a checkbox returning true
I am trying to increase the value of a cell everytime a checkbox returns as true but everything i have tried ends up as circular. Is there a way that I would be able to do this?
I tried using =if(A2="true", B2+1, B2) in B2 but that ended up being circular.

You cannot use a formula to reference it's own calculation result as a starting point, you need vba

You can use Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) to increment values based on a checkbox toggle.

In your Excel document, press Alt + F11.
Double-click your sheet from the left panel under 'Project - VBAProject'.
Paste the following script (change target cells as necessary):


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value = True Then
            Range("B2").Value = Range("B2").Value + 1
        End If
    End If
End Sub


Close the editor.


This script reads the checkbox in A2. Whenever it's toggled, it increments B2 by 1.

This worked great! thanks for the easy instructions as I did not know about VBA before this.

Do the following:

Place the code below, in the sheet's code module
Select the sheet, click Developer -> Insert -> Forms -> Checkbox
Create the checkbox and then in Design mode right-click and select Assign macro and select from the list Sheet1.inccheck (actual name of the sheet)
Close the window

Sub inccheck()

If Worksheets("Sheet1").CheckBoxes("check box 1") = 1 Then

Range("E3") = Range("E3") + 1

End If
End Sub

Replace "Sheet1" with the actual name of the sheet.
Replace "check box 1" with the actual name of the checkbox. (displayed in the top left corner of the sheet in the Name Box. (only english version)
Replace "E3" with the cell address you want to increment.
